# Wifi from my esp32 M5 StickC plus does not work

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, platformio

I am trying to connect to my wifi using my M5StickCPlus. I use the platformIO framework. I am getting this error : error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' at compilation.

Here is the code:

```
#include "M5StickCPlus.h"
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* WIFI_SSID =  "router";
const char* WIFI_PASS = "pass";

void setup() {
   M5.begin(true, true, true);
   Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", WIFI_SSID);
   WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
   }
  Serial.println("CONNECTED");
}
```

I also tried to declare the SSID and the password using #define. But, I am getting another error : addApbChangeCallback(): duplicate func=400EAB44 arg=3FFBF008 during execution.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WiFi.begin()` function overload that takes two arguments (an SSID and a password) requires the first argument to be a **non-const** `char*` pointer (i.e. a pointer to a *potentially* modifiable `char` array, even if the function doesn't actually change it).

A simple way around this (similar to the [example given in the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiBegin)) is to redeclare your `WIFI_SSID` variable as such an array and initialize it with a *copy* of the string literal. (You can also do the same for the `WIFI_PASS` argument, but that is not *required*, as the second argument to `begin()` is a `const char*`.):

```cpp
char WIFI_SSID[] = "router";    // Change to a non-const char array
const char* WIFI_PASS = "pass"; // You can leave this one as-is
```

---

**NOTE:** The declaration of that `begin()` overload, as in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFi/blob/master/src/WiFi.h), is:

```cpp
int begin(char* ssid, const char *passphrase);
```

An implicit conversion from a `const` pointer to a non-const pointer is not allowed in C++; you *could* use a `const_cast<char*>(WIFI_SSID)` on your current definition but, IMHO, that is a less desirable approach – the argument will have been defined as non-const for a reason, even if that reason is not obvious!

Comment: Thank you for the response ! The code compiles but I still get this error :  [E][esp32-hal-cpu.c:93] addApbChangeCallback(): duplicate func=400EAB58 arg=3FFBF018 in the serial terminal. The code will not execute further than the wifi.begin

Comment: @HealthyDev I think you should post that issue as a new, separate question. It *may* be related but I can't see an *obvious* link.